# Program hangs possibly due to lambda closures or dispatcher issue

Tags: c#, callback, closures, dispatcher, ui-thread

I implemented an experimental lightweight in-memory message bus, where recipients can subscribe to messages via the `Subscribe()` method which I pasted below.

A sender can send messages and the message bus will invoke an internal call back `internalCallback`. Before the callback is invoked the message may be deep-cloned and marshaled onto a UI thread.

**This is where my problem arises**: When I comment out the UI dispatcher (as is done in the snippet below) then the callback is invoked correctly. With the dispatcher active the entire application hangs (no run-time error is thrown). What confuses me even more is that the entire below code worked perfectly fine when I ran the calling method on a UI thread. But now the entire framework may also send messages on different tasks/threads and this is when problems arose.

What should I be looking into or possibly adjust?

Thanks

```
public void Subscribe<T>(string subscriberId, string topic, Action<string, T> callback, bool returnOnUiThread, bool makeDeepCopy, bool catchAll)
    {
        //create new peer connection if it does not yet exist
        if (!_peerConnections.ContainsKey(subscriberId))
        {
            var newPeer = new PeerConnection(subscriberId)
            {
                ConnectionStatus = PeerConnectionStatus.Connected,
                CreationTimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                LastAliveTimeStamp = DateTime.Now
            };

            _peerConnections.Add(subscriberId, newPeer);
        }

        var internalCallBack = new Action<string, object>((header, msg) =>
        {
            //make a deep copy via serialization if requested
            if (makeDeepCopy == true)
            {
                //try deep clone
                var serializedObject = Serializers.JsonStringFromObject(msg);
                msg = Serializers.ObjectFromJsonString<T>(serializedObject);
            }

            var handle = callback;
            handle(header, (T)msg);

            ////return on ui thread if requested
            //if (returnOnUiThread == true)
            //{
            //    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            //    {
            //        var handle = callback;
            //        handle(header, (T)msg);
            //    });
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    var handle = callback;
            //    handle(header, (T)msg);
            //}
        });

        //adding subscription to collection
        var subscription = new Subscription(subscriberId, topic, internalCallBack, catchAll);
        _subscriptions.Add(subscription);
    }
```

Comment: Generally you should use `BeginInvoke` as the `Invoke` can lead to a deadlock

Comment: _"...Before the callback is invoked the message may be deep-cloned and **marshaled onto a UI thread**..."_ - this isn't COM.  In .NET object ownership isn't associated with a thread.  The exception being the UI must be updated via the UI/main thread

Comment: @MickyD, BeginInvoke works, I still try to wrap my head around the reason for the deadlock, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `BeginInvoke` as the `Invoke` can lead to a deadlock.  `Invoke` is kind of a lock so it will wait, blocking the current thread until the action finishes.  `BeginInvoke` places the request onto the *Windows Message Pump* where it will be processed by the UI thread later without blocking the worker thread.

Even though the Windows GUI isn't multithreaded, you can still deadlock it.  Checkout the article below.

### More

- *[Multithreaded toolkits: A failed dream? Blog](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kgh/2004/10/19/multithreaded-toolkits-failed-dream)*, Oracle, October 19 2004